# Take particular Key and values from JSON response using python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a different kind of JSON format. I am stuck on how to get the 1st Key alone.

My JSON RESPONSE:

```
resp={
"root[0]": {
"Name": "res1",
"region": "ca-1",
"tags": [
  {
    "name": "Environment",
    "value": "TC1"
  },     
  {
    "name": "Test",
    "value": "yes"
  }
]
},
"root[3]": {
"Name": "Demo",
"region": "ca-1",
"tags": [
  {
    "name": "Test1",
    "value": "check"
  },

  {
    "name": "Test12",
    "value": "yes"
  }
]
```

}
}

I want to take the Name and Region key and values alone. Note that root[] will have any number inside so I cant explicitly put the number as it changes every time.

Python Code

```
test = resp.get('Name')
test2= resp.get('region')
print(test,test2)
##Both prints None
```

Expected:

```
 "Name": "res1",
 "region": "ca-1",
 "Name": "Demo",
 "region": "ca-1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple task if you loop through the dict:

```
test = {
"root[0]": {
"Name": "res1",
"region": "ca-1",
"tags": [
  {
    "name": "Environment",
    "value": "TC1"
  },     
  {
    "name": "Test",
    "value": "yes"
  }
]
},
"root[3]": {
"Name": "Demo",
"region": "ca-1",
"tags": [
  {
    "name": "Test1",
    "value": "check"
  },

  {
    "name": "Test12",
    "value": "yes"
  }
]
}}
for k in test:
  print(test[k]["Name"])
  print(test[k]["region"])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to obtain the values related to a specific key of your `resp` object (for example, `"root[0]"`) you can use the following solution:

```
number = 0 # your chosen number (the one inside root)
name = resp[f"root[{number}]"]["Name"]
region = resp[f"root[{number}]"]["region"]
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to iterate the dict.

**Ex:**

```
for _, v in resp.items():
    print(v['Name'], v['region'])
```

**Output:**

```
res1 ca-1
Demo ca-1
```

Answer (score 1):

a rough approach given resp is your provided dict:

```
for k, v in resp.items():
    for kk, vv in v.items():
        if kk == "Name" or kk == "region":
            print(kk, vv)
```

output would be:

```
Name res1
region ca-1
Name Demo
region ca-1
```